# Как найти совпадения индексов сравнивая с двумя списками?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть индексы df:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Есть, список образованный из df:

```
l_figure_s= [5,12,19,24,29,66,72,   76, 84, 91]
```

Есть, список образованный из df:

```
l_figure_e= [11,15,22,27,62,69,75,82,   87, 99]
```

Из списков образован

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'starts':l_figure_s,'ends':l_figure_e},dtype=int,orient='index').transpose()
```

Как нужно написать на pandas сравнение индексов df cо значениями столбцов 'starts' и 'ends' из df1, по следующему условию :

```
df.index >= df1['starts'] & df.index <= df1['ends'] &  df1['starts'] < df1['ends'] & df1['starts'].shift(-1) > df1['ends']
```

В итоге получиться df в котором будут строки по индексно `(5,6,7,8,9,10,11)` `(12,13,14,15)` и так далее..

Comment: Ну, простого варианта не вижу, только перебором строк df1. А что вы сами уже пробовали делать? Я могу написать, но почему я должен потратить своё время, если это просто рутинная работа, ничего тут хитрого нет, просто сесть и написать.

Comment: Кстати, ваша конструкция `df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'starts':l_figure_s,'ends':l_figure_e},dtype=int,orient='index').transpose()`  избыточна. Проще и быстрее сделать так: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'starts':l_figure_s,'ends':l_figure_e},dtype=int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сначала отсейте из df1 те строки, которые не удовлетворяют вашему условию (df1['starts'] < df1['ends'] & df1['starts'].shift(-1) > df1['ends']), только имейте в виду, что шифтованные колонки опасно сравнивать, потому как теряются крайние значения. затем:

```
res = df1.apply(lambda x: [(y >= x.starts) & (y <= x.ends) for y in df.index], axis=1).apply(lambda k: [i for i,j in enumerate(k) if j]).to_list()
print(res)
```

```
[[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [19, 20, 21, 22], [24, 25, 26, 27], [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62], [66, 67, 68, 69], [72, 73, 74, 75], [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82], [84, 85, 86, 87], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```